# Authenticating with Netflix: Netflix OAuth vs. SignPost OAuth: Which is correct?

Tags: java, oauth, netflix, signpost

With signpost 1.2:

```
String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken( consumer, callbackUrl );
```

Netflix API response:

```
<status>
  <status_code>
    400
  </status_code>
  <message>
    oauth_consumer_key is missing
  </message>
</status>
```

I see how to craft the URL manually via the [netflix documentation](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/Security#0_18325), but this seems to contradict other services which use OAuth authentication. Who's incorrect, here? Is there a way to get signpost to work with Netflix, aside from contributing to the signpost source? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon retrieving the request token, simply add this line of code to your application:

```
authUrl = OAuth.addQueryParameters(authUrl, OAuth.OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, 
CONSUMER_KEY, "application_name", APPLICATION_NAME);
```